# Essential Grid not showing up in Wordpress posts

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Well...the problem is that ... Ess. Grid is not showing up in posts for a one page. It's a custom made template. Maybe there is something wrong with my post loop. Maybe there is something wrong with my jquerys.

The loop

```
case 'gallery':
            $a_div_st = '<div id="';
            $cat_name = $category->name;
            $a_div_st_e = '" class="container-fluid">';
            $a_div_end = '</div>';

            $g_args = array(
                        'category_name' => 'gallery',
                        'post_type'      => 'post',
                        'orderby'        => 'date',
                        'order'          => 'ASC',
                        );
            $gallery = new WP_Query($g_args);
            if($gallery->have_posts()){
            echo $a_div_st.$cat_name.$a_div_st_e;


                while($gallery->have_posts()){
                    $gallery->the_post();
                        echo '<h1>';
                            the_title();
                        echo '</h2>';

                        the_content();

                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            echo $a_div_end;
            }

            break;
```

Sorry for the unorganized code. I have never made WP templates.

Comment: Detail : You're opening an H1 but closing and H2

Comment: Yeah, saw that after i posted ... still not displaying the grid.